# How can I get the URI to the file with 3 different file choosers?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have 3 different buttons: Upload Profile Picture, Upload Photo ID and Upload Criminal Record Photo, but after I call the openFileChooser() method which I created, I don't know how exactly I have to handle that to get 3 different URls.

I mean I did this

```
public class SignupCarrier extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editfullname, editemail, editpassword, editconfirmpassword, editaddress, editcity, editstate, editzipcode, editcountry, editphone, editcardnumber, editexpiredate, editcvc;
Button upProfile, upIDPhoto, upCriminalRecord;
private Uri mProfilePic, mIdPhoto,mCriminalRecord;
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private StorageTask mUploadTask;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_carrier);


        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        upProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        upIDPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idphotoPic);
        upCriminalRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.criminalRecord);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("carriersPictures");

        upProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });
        upIDPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });
        upCriminalRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            mProfilePic = data.getData();


        }
    }
}
```

But this would probably work only for upProfile Button, how can I modify the onActivityResult to get for each buttons the URLs?

Thank you! I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Uri` as parameter to your `openFileChooser()` method.

`private void openFileChooser(Uri uri)`

and call it like this:

```
upProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFileChooser(mProfilePic);
        }
    });
```

Update your `openFileChooser()` method to this:

```
private void openFileChooser(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    if (uri == mProfilePic) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    } else if (uri == mIdPhoto) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID);
    } else if (uri == mCriminalRecord) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR);
    }
}
```

You need to declare these constants: `PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID`, `PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR`

And in your `onActivityResult()` method check the `requestCode` to handle each case

Comment: thanks, and then how I return it? I mean in the onActivityResult what get the data.getData();?

Comment: What would you like to return? I don't understand what do you want to do.

Comment: I have 3 buttons. Upload Profile Picture, Upload ID photo and Upload Criminal Record. After they click a button and select the image  I want to get the Url to that image.

Comment: After fileChooser I call onAcivityResult, but there I get the url but for which of those buttons?

Comment: Where should I use that value I pass with the paramater